# Is a "Golem" the same thing as a person created through Sefer Yetzirah?

Tags: creation, practical-kabbalah, artificial-lifeform

Is a "Golem" the same thing as a person created through Sefer Yetzirah? Please be clear with your answer.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6053

Comment: Aaron Levian, thanks for the interesting question, which would be improved by your including in it your basis for asking (why do you think a "_golem_" might be someone created via _Sefer Y'tzira_?). Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: Is a "Golem" even a formal category?

Comment: I know nothing about it, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2902/1561

Answer (score 4):

Creating people through the use of Sefer Yetzira is mentioned in Gemora Sanhedrin 65b and Rashi there. It seems that common usage of the word "golem" refers to such a practice. In [Rabbi Chaim Volozhin's introduction to "Sefer Dezniyusa"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31539&st=&pgnum=6) of the Gaon of Vilna he relates that the Gr"a told him that he had a very precise version of Sefer Yetzira to which R' Chaim noted that if so it would not be difficult to create a golem. The Gr"a responded that he had in fact attempted to do so (when he was not yet even thirteen years old) but received a heavenly sign to stop. This is one source that uses the word "golem" to refer to someone created by Sefer Yetzirah.