# Can a robot count in a minyan?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, technology, minyan, artificial-lifeform

Can a robot count in a minyan? [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6054/4648) brings that a robot is not Mechuyav in Mitzvot. I'd like to know if there are sources stating any other reasons (if any).

Comment: The Itche Kadoozy Show comes to mind. :D "Jono, what would robots need to pray for?" "The ability to love."

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/does-robot-golem

Comment: Is the robot Jewish? _Can_ a robot be Jewish?

Comment: Are you looking for a place that specifically mentioned a robot, or is it anything that proves a robot can or cannot be counted?

Comment: Why would you think it could

Comment: @ABochur, both aspects with sources would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[R. Tzvi Hirsch Ashkenazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzvi_Ashkenazi) has a responsum (Shu"t Chacham Tzvi siman 93) about whether a being created using the Sefer Yetzira can count for a minyan, and his conclusion is that it cannot.

> אלא ודאי שאינו מצטרף לעשרה לכל דבר שבקדושה כך נ"ל

Similarly, [R. Hayim Joseph David Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) cites (Birchei Yosef O.C. 55:4) the son of the Sha'ar Ephraim as proving that it would not count for a minyan, though R. Azulai himself rejects the proof.

> וראיתי במכתב להרב מהר"י ליב כ"ץ בן הרב שער אפרים שהביא ראיה מההיא דרבי
>   אליעזר דשחרר עבדו ועבר אעשה דלעולם בהם תעבודו ואם איתא דמצטרף יברא אדם
>   ע"י ספר יצירה דרבי אליעזר גדול כחו כמ"ש במדרש הנעלם עכ"ד ואנא דאמרי
>   דאינה ראיה כלל דלאיי האיכא כח גברא רבה ר' אליעזר כי שיח וכי שיג לו ומי
>   לנו גדול מ"מ אפשר דממדת חסידות מעולם לא בעי עביד ותו דלמא כל כי הא בעי
>   הכנה הרבה והזמנה מילתא ולאו כל שעתא מצי עביד ותו לפי מ"ש הר"ן פרק
>   השולח והביאו מרן כ"מ סוף הלכות עבדים, שלא אמרה תורה לעולם בהם תעבודו
>   אלא משום שלא יתן להם מתנת חינם וכיון דאיכא מצוה לאו משום חנינה דידיהו
>   עביד אלא לצורך הו"ל כנותן דמי עצמו א"כ אין כאן הוכחה דלא עבר אמידי

Why would a robot would be better than such a creature? If anything it should be worse, because at least the Sefer-Yetzira-creature is in some way alive.

In fact, in an addendum to the responsum, R. Tzvi Hirsch Ashkenazi specifically states that to count for a minyan one must have a "human soul", which a robot does not have:

> שכיון שאין בו אפילו נפש אדם אין לו עסק וענין עם דברים הטעונים עשרה או
>   שלשה נפשות מישראל

Answer (score 4):

The Orach Chayim says that in order to say kaddish, we must have at least 10 **men** (not robots) in the room.

[Orach Chayim 55:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.55.1)

> אומרים קדיש וא"א אותו בפחות מי' זכרים  בני חורין גדולים שהביאו ב'
>   שערות וה"ה לקדושה וברכו שאין נאמרין בפחות מעשרה:
>
> We say Kaddish, and it is not said with less than ten males, who are
>   free and have grown two [pubic] hairs, and this is the rule for
>   Kedushah and Barchu that are not said with less than ten.

And if you're sceptical whether זכרים is actually taking about male humans and not animals or robots, below you'll see that it says it must be *bnei adam* - humans:

From the [Aruch Hashulchan 1.69.1](https://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.69.1)

> תנן במגילה (כג ב): אין פורסין על "שמע", ואין עוברין לפני התיבה בפחות
>   מעשרה. ולפירוש רש"י כפי מה שביאר הר"ן, הכי פירושו: כגון שהיו כאן
>   **עשרה בני אדם** שהתפללו כל אחד בפני עצמו ביחידות, ולא שמעו לא קדיש ולא קדושה – עומד אחד מהם ואומר קדיש, ו"ברכו", וברכה ראשונה ד"יוצר".
>   וזהו לשון "פורסין" כמו "פרוסה", כלומר: מחצית הברכות. ואם תאמר: למה להו
>   ברכה זו, הא כבר אמרו זה ביחידות? ויש לומר: או מפני קדושת "יוצר", אם
>   נאמר דאינו אומרה ביחיד כמו שיש סוברין כן, כמו שכתבתי בסימן נ"ט. או
>   כיון ששליח הציבור אומר להם "ברכו" – בעל כרחם צריכין לברך איזה ברכה.
>   דאם לא כן נראים ככופרים חס ושלום, שאומר להם לברך ואינם מברכים, לכך
>   מברכים "יוצר אור" (בית יוסף). ואינו מובן: הא ענו "ברוך המבורך לעולם
>   ועד", מה שייך ככופרים? הרי גם בקריאת התורה כן הוא (רמ"א בדרכי משה).

Answer (score 0):

I saw an article that discusses this question: https://www.jta.org/2014/06/12/life-religion/should-robots-count-in-a-minyan-rabbi-talks-turing-test

Another thing; if a robot can count for a minyan, can a robot do mitzvos? If they could, we can make many robots that will learn Torah all day and create a lot of mitzvos. Just a thought :)

And while we're on the topic, one is considered a jew if their 'creator', I.E. their mother 'made' them by concieving and giving birth to them. So would a robot made by a jew be considerd a jew, and a robot made by a non jew be considered a non jew? I am well aware that it is possible to be mechalek between birth by a mother and creation of a robot using machines and technology, but I thought there also might be makom to compare the two and hence thought I would throw this out there as food for thought. edit - the user called 'Alex' messaged me that the Chacham Tzvi says a similar sevara, that a being created through the sefer yetzira may be considered jewish if it/he/she was created by a jew.

Comment: I'm wondering if there rabbi there is joking or not

Comment: @ABochur its pretty clear that he meant it seriously. For example he says that the discussion is l'halacha v'lo l'imaaseh. And he's writing a book about it.

Comment: What does lehalacha but not lemaase mean? What's a good example of something similar? Btw I'm wondering if this rabbi hold that you have to wait till the robot is 13 years old..

Comment: @ABoc it's a reference to Horyot 2a and it's quite common in speculative Halakhic literature

Comment: @ABochur  the reason why one would need to be 13 years old is because until then they have no 'daas'. When robots are created, they are created with their full cognitive function. Therefore I would argue that a robot has 'daas' from day one of its creation and not at 13 years old (going under the assumption that robots have consciousness and are halachicly similar to people).